# C++ std::unordered_map complexity

Tags: c++, stl, iteration, time-complexity, unordered-map

I've read a lot about [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) *(c++11)* **time-complexity** here at stackoverflow, but I haven't found the answer for my question.

Let's assume indexing by integer (just for example):

Insert/at functions work constantly (in average time), so this example would take O(1)

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> mymap = {
            { 1, 1},
            { 100, 2},
            { 100000, 3 }
};
```

**What I am curious about is how long does it take to iterate through all (unsorted) values stored in map - e.g.**

```
for ( auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it ) { ... }
```

Can I assume that each stored value is accessed only once (or twice or constant-times)? That would imply that iterate through all values is in N-valued map O(N). The other possibility is that my example with keys {1,10,100000} could take up to 1000000 iteration (if represented by array)

Is there any other container, that can be iterated linearly and value accessed by given key constantly?

**What I would really need is** (pseudocode)

```
myStructure.add(key, value) // O(1)
value = myStructure.at(key) // O(1)
for (auto key : mySructure) {...} // O(1) for each key/value pair = O(N) for N values
```

Is std::unordered_map the structure I need?

Integer indexing is sufficient, average complexity as well.

Comment: If you're concerned that the enumeration will require walking over pairings that you've *not* inserted into your container, rest assured it won't. The decision to use a regular `map` vs `unordered_map` should be based on whether you need a relative strict weak ordering of your keys *retained*. If you do, you need a regular `map`. If you don't, `unordered_map` is the most logical choice (provided the keys can be hashed to a reasonable distribution).

Comment: @WhozCraig: another functional factor to consider when choosing `map` or `unordered_map` is whether the latter's invalidation of existing iterators/references/pointers during `insert`/`emplace`/`[]` triggering rehashing is acceptable, then there're performance differences which *tend* to be in `unordered_map`'s favour but should be measured by those whose profilers/instrumentation says must really care....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Regardless of how they're implemented, standard containers provide iterators that meet the iterator requirements. Incrementing an iterator is required to be constant time, so iterating through all the elements of **any** standard container is O(N).

Comment: I can't seem to find the complexity requirement for increment (nor dereference for that matter). Do you have a citation?

Comment: According to SGI's `forward iterator` concept *the complexity guarantee of operations on forward iterators is guaranteed to be amortized constant time*. Section 24.4.4 of the C++ Standard only states *for input, forward, and bidirectional iterators [...] they use ++ to provide linear time implementations*.

Comment: @Arrieta: For the case of `unordered_map`, it is ambiguous what "linear" means. It can mean either "number of buckets" or "elements in container". Is there something more concrete that indicates the latter?

Comment: @jxh: I cannot find anything in the Standard ;(

Comment: @jxh: I found the following: *All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized). Therefore, requirement tables for the iterators do not have a complexity column.* (cf. 24.2.1.8). So increment is only required to be amortized constant time for elements in container (as I understand it).

Comment: @Arrieta: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. However, amortized time assumes that the bad case happens infrequently. But, an `unodered_map` configured with a million buckets, but hashes only 2 items, one at the first bucket, and one in the last, can still claim amortized constant time for increment, even if in reality it always requires a million increments to get from the first item to the second.

Comment: @jxh - there is no time complexity for iterating over an `unordered_container` with M buckets and N elements. Time complexity is about **asymptotic** behavior, not about any one case. Linear time complexity means **only** that for large numbers of elements if, for example, you double the number of elements in the container you double the time needed for an operation. What happens for small numbers of elements is irrelevant.

Comment: I am not disputing that O notation is about asymptotic behavior, but the question is regarding the specific example of 3 insertions. However, my tests with GCC show that the iteration cost is not measurably different for sparse or dense hash table. I've already +1'd your answer and deleted my own.

Comment: @jxh: default `max_load_factor` is 1, for which worst-case iteration is an N-node linked-list traversal in the bucket where all values collide, and a (much cheaper due to contiguous memory) check that the other N-1 buckets are empty.  Only in the insane case of writing code that manually and repeatedly calls `max_load_factor` using a value not linearly related to `size()` would the iteration complexity differ from `O(N)`.  Re "my tests... not measurably different for sparse or dense" - it may well differ if you're describing `load_factor`, but not for numerical sparseness of keys per the Q.

Comment: @TonyD: I used to be ignorant of the meaning of `load_factor` but I have since wised up. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Incrementing an iterator in a balanced tree (`std::map` or `std::set`) is not O(1), but rather O(logN). Though amortized complexity of iterating over the whole balanced tree is O(N).

Answer (score 5):

The complexity guarantees of all standard containers are specified in the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

`std::unordered_map` element access and element insertion is required to be of complexity `O(1)` on average and `O(N)` worst case (cf. Sections 23.5.4.3 and 23.5.4.4; pages 797-798).

A specific implementation (that is, a specific vendor's implementation of the Standard Library) can choose whatever data structure they want. However, to be compliant with the Standard, their complexity must be *at least* as specified.

Comment: Is that complexity also `O(N)` in the worst case when using iterators? (more specifically, incrementing an iterator by 1?)

Comment: As it has been answered above, the traversing of *all* the container is required to be `O(N)` (a `std::unordered_map` iterator fulfills the `forward iterator` concept). Accessing a **specific** element or **inserting** an element is `O(1)` on average and `O(N)` worst case.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few different ways that a hash table can be implemented, and I suggest you read more on those if you're interested, but the main two are through chaining and open addressing.

In the first case you have an array of linked lists. Each entry in the array could be empty, each item in the hashtable will be in some bucket. So iteration is walking down the array, and walking down each non-empty list in it. Clearly O(N), but could potentially be very memory inefficient depending on how the linked lists themselves are allocated.

In the second case, you just have one very large array which will have lots of empty slots. Here, iteration is again clearly linear, but could be inefficient if the table is mostly empty (which is should be for lookup purposes) because the elements that are actually present will be in different cache lines.

Either way, you're going to have linear iteration and you're going to be touching every element exactly once. Note that this is true of `std::map` also, iteration will be linear there as well. But in the case of the maps, iteration will definitely be far less efficient that iterating a vector, so keep that in mind. If your use-case involves requiring BOTH fast lookup and fast iteration, if you insert all your elements up front and never erase, it could be much better to actually have both the map and the vector. Take the extra space for the added performance.