# Time complexity of iterating through a C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I know that the unordered_map in C++ STL is implemented as hashtable consisting of buckets that correspond to hashed values. The time for insertions, deletions and element search is guaranteed to be amortized constant. However I don't quite understand how the iterator works on this data structure. When I increment the iterator, how does it know where is the next position? And what would the time complexity be when I iterated through a unordered_map using an iterator?  Is the time used to find the next position of the iterator constant ? I found some information on the internal structure of unordered_map in the book *The C++ Standard Library: A tutorial and Reference* but I couldn't find the answer to my questions. Hope someone can help!

Thanks.

Comment: This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610457/c-stdunordered-map-complexity?rq=1) says any standard container must provide O(1) iterators. (I suggest removing this question unless it's actually different than the linked one).

Comment: Pulled this from one of the comments, "Section 24.4.4 of the C++ Standard," gives requirements for the ++ operator on forward iterators. Good question. I enjoyed this trip. :)

Comment: @sam If it's a "good" question, then there's no reason to remove it! Flag as duplicate, if applicable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hash tables are implemented using buckets that contain linked lists. So iterating is easy:

1. See if the current node has a next pointer. If so, go to that.
2. If the current node has no next pointer, go to the next bucket that has a node.
3. If there is no such node, then you're done iterating.

(Find the first node by finding the first bucket with a node in it.)

Intuitively, since iterating through the whole hash table using the above algorithm is O(n), it would appear that each "next" operation is amortised constant time.

Comment: It isn't exactly O(n), rather it is O(N+n), where N is the number of buckets. This is because each bucket needs to be visited at least once even if it had no elements. These are typically a constant factor away from each other, which is why this is fine.