# equality comparison of two std::unordered_map fails

Tags: c++

How to check for equality of two [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) using `std::equal` to check if both containers have same keys and their corresponding key values. Below my code prints `unequal` even though both containers have same size, set of keys and the corresponding key values are equal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<char, int> um1, um2;
    um1['f'] = 1;
    um1['o'] = 1;
    um1['r'] = 1;

    um2['o'] = 1;
    um2['r'] = 1;
    um2['f'] = 1;

    if (um1.size() == um2.size() && std::equal(um1.begin(), um1.end(), um2.begin()))
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "unequal" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `If (um1 == um2)`?

Comment: keep in mind that is is an **unordered** map, so the order in which the iterators will iterate the keys is unspecified and can be seemingly random. This would work with a `std::map`, since it will sort it's elements in a consistent way. But `std::unordered_map` is implemented as a hashmap, so the order in which you will get the elements depends on the hash function, bucket size and insertion order. (it might also change down the line if a rehashing occurs)

Comment: Refer to this- https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operators/

Comment: @NathanOliver it's giving me the required output. Does this work for any insertion order?

Comment: [`unordered_map::operator ==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp).

Comment: @Harry operator== will work for any insertion order. keep in mind however that comparing two unordered_maps can be a lot more expensive than comparing two normal maps (due to their unsorted nature) - comparing `std::map`s will be at most `O(n)` while comparing `std::unsorted_map`s can be up to `O(n²)`. (with n being the number of elements in the map)

Comment: It should still be O(n) to iterate over an unordered_map, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195233/time-complexity-of-iterating-through-a-c-unordered-map Then you have two O(1) lookups for the values to compare, which is a constant multiplier.

Comment: What you should have done is pretty well covered in comments. I posted on why std::equal doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: @KennyOstrom the gotcha is that the equality function and hash function for the unordered_map's might be different from the normal comparison function for the contained objects. [example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y37nM6fTE) So you can't use the `O(1)` lookup but rather have to rely on `equal_range()` and check if the groups you get from each container are permutations of each other (which is rather expensive to do). This is also documented on the [`std::unordered_map::operator== page`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp)

Comment: Oh, right, worst case. Okay, fair point, but the average case is O(N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

> Two ranges are considered equal if they have the same number of elements and, for every iterator i in the range [first1,last1), *i equals *(first2 + (i - first1)).

Consider this code added to your code snippet:

```
for (auto it : um1)
    std::cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
for (auto it : um2)
    std::cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << std::endl;
```

> f: 1
> o: 1
> r: 1
>
> o: 1
> r: 1
> f: 1

Note that the iteration happens in a different order, as you should expect. Therefore they are not std::equal because (as documented above) that expects the same values in the same order.

However, this specitic container has its own operator== as noted in the comments, which checks for value equality as you were originally expecting for this specific container.